# Contador de tiempo

Tags: java, bucle-for

estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio en Java y me he quedado en blanco:

Implementa el método reproducir, que reproducirá los segundos de objeto multimedia.
La implementación de este método solo escribirá en consola la secuencia de segundos transcurridos hasta que finalice, según la duración.
Por ejemplo, si dura 70 segundos (1 minuto 10 segundos), escribirá: 00:00:01—00:00:02—00:00:03—00:00:04 --...-00:00:59—00:01:00 ... 00:01:10 [Fin]

```
    static void reproducir(int duracion) {
    int horas = 00;
    int minutos = 00;
    int segundos = 00;
    final int N = 59;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= duracion; i++) {
        if (segundos == N) {
            segundos = 0;
            minutos++;
        }

        if (minutos == N) {
            minutos = 0;
            horas++;
        }
        segundos++;
        System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d - ", horas, minutos, segundos);
    }
    System.out.print("Fin de la reproducción");
}
```

Método funcionando después de la revisión.

Comment: Verifica esto: `for(i=0, i=duracion, i++){`, estás realizando una asignación (`i = duracion`) cuando deberías tener una comparación (`i <= duracion`). Empieza por allí. Además dentro del bucle tienes: `segudos++;` Debería ser: `segundos++;`, te falta la letra `n`.

Comment: Modificado, pero no va aún

Comment: Es que no estás calculando nada. Solo tienes un bucle que aumenta segundos cada iteración. Los segundos subirán y subirán muy rápido. Miles de veces en un instante (si duración lo permitiera). No estás aumentando cada segundo, sino cada iteración del bucle. Luego está que no estás calculando minutos ni horas. Cuando segundos es 60, deberías tener 1 minuto, pero no lo estás haciendo. Solo tienes un bucle, no estás calculando tiempo de nada. Al menos en el código que has mostrado. ¿En el ejercicio tienes algún objeto multimedia que reproducir? ¿O solo simular el paso del tiempo?

Comment: Solo es simular el paso del tiempo, este método va dentro de una simulación de AppTV, donde ire metiendo objetos del tipo películas, anuncios, etc, y simulare simplemente eso, por lo tanto no necesito que pase cada segundo, sino simplemente que pinte en consola 00:00:00  00:00:01 hasta la duración que le diga

Comment: @ArianJM tiene razón. El bucle solo va desde *cero* a *duracion*, debes implementar una forma de calcular los minutos y las horas basado en lo segundos que tienes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entiendo que es una simulación, no cuenta el paso del tiempo realmente.

Lo que necesitas es calcular minutos y horas dependiendo del tiempo que ha pasado. Esta sería tu función:

```
public static void reproducir(int duracion) {
    int horas = 0;
    int minutos = 0;
    int segundos = 0;
    int totalSegundos = 0;

    for (totalSegundos = 0; totalSegundos <= duracion; totalSegundos++){
        segundos = totalSegundos % 60;
        minutos = (int) Math.floor(totalSegundos / 60) % 60;
        horas = (int) Math.floor(totalSegundos / 3600);

        System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", horas, minutos, segundos );
    }
}
```

Segundos son de 0 a 59, así que `segundos = totalSegundos % 60`.

Cada 60 segundos hay un minuto, así que `minutos = totalSegundos / 60`. Además, minutos son de 0 a 59, así que hacemos modulo 60 respecto con los minutos que salgan.

Cada 3600 segundos (60 * 60) hay una hora, así que `horas = totalSegundos / 3600`

Comment: Perfecto , he editado la pregunta, porque había dado con un método mientras.

Comment: @LuisQuesadaRomero tu forma actual funciona en tu simulación, pero la que yo propongo es más correcta. Imagínate en el caso real de que es una reproducción. Si el usuario pasa del segundo 15 al segundo 62, la hemos fastidiado. Nunca entrará al if, los minutos se quedarán en 0 y los segundos subirán sin mirar atrás. En mi caso, los cálculos dirán que es el segundo 2 del minuto 1, y listos.